# Ldap 3 Python Смена пароля

Tags: python, ldap

```
ad_dn = "CN=User,OU=Office,DC=domen,DC=domen"
username = 'User'
new_pwd = 'SD782Jsdaas2'   
newpwd_utf16 = '"{0}"'.format(new_pwd).encode('utf-16-le')
mod_list = [
   (MODIFY_REPLACE, "unicodePwd", newpwd_utf16),
]
conn.modify(ad_dn.format(username), mod_list)
```

Пытаюсь поменять пароль, выдаёт ошибку:

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPChangeError: changes must be a dictionary
```

Как я могу это решить?

Comment: В ошибке всё написано - `changes` должны быть словарем, а вы зачем-то передаёте лист. В docstring у modify есть пример.

Comment: Сделал по другому, но стала выпадать другая ошибка  
    pwd = 'SD782Jsdaas2' 
            enc_pwd = '"{}"'.format(pwd).encode('utf-16-le')
            conn.modify(ad_dn, {'unicodePwd': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, [enc_pwd])]})
            print(conn.result)
{'result': 53, 'description': 'unwillingToPerform', 'dn': '', 'message': '0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A1262, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n\x00', 'referrals': None, 'type': 'modifyResponse'}

Comment: погуглил за вас: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797955/how-do-i-resolve-will-not-perform-ms-ad-reply-when-trying-to-change-password-i

Answer (score 1):

```
def search_ad(last='*', login='*'):
c.bind()
c.search('ou=Офис,dc=DOMAIN,dc=local',
         '(&(objectCategory=Person)(sn={})(sAMAccountName={}))'.format(last, login), SUBTREE,
         attributes=['sAMAccountName', 'givenName', 'sn', 'cn', 'whenCreated', 'lastLogon', 'pwdLastSet',
                     'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed', 'memberOf', 'ipPhone', 'lockoutTime',
                     'distinguishedName'])
a = c.entries
c.unbind()
return a



place = search_ad(last=login.split(" ")[1])
    for i in place:
            place = str(i['distinguishedName'])
    place = place[place.find(",") + 1:]
    c.bind()
    a = c.extend.microsoft.modify_password(user='cn=' + login + ',' + str(place), new_password=uis_password)
    c.unbind()
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ваш ответ - но ваш пример ничего не изменил.
Пароль сменить не получается.
В вашем примере есть поиск - по факту нужен только DN, для примера работы скрипта я могу его получить из PowerShell скриптом:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity _user_logon_ -Properties 
* | Select-Object _atrr_name_
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/751388)